# Rsync not persisting timestamps on directories with sub directories being copied

Tags: ssh, rsync

I've got rsync copying data between 2 unraid systems nightly. I noticed recently that some directories kept being flagged for copy by rsync (but only the folder themselves not the contents).

I'm using the following:

```
rsync -vW -rlt -e "ssh -i ssh.key" -og --chown=nobody:users --chmod=D777,F666 -p --delete "/mnt/user/Media/" "root@192.168.1.3:/mnt/user/Media/"
```

If I have the following directory structure for movies/tv shows etc:

```
Movie_Name
│   movie.mkv    
│
└───extras
│   │
│   └───extra1
│       │   exta1.mkv
│       │   ...
```

The timestamp on the mkv files are fine, but randomly the timestamp on the folders are wrong. Instead of using the source timestamp they use the creation time on the destination. The one consistent I have noticed is it only seems to happen to directories with sub directories. Directories with a single mkv file are fine.

I know I can essentially ignore this by adding -O (--omit-dir-times) but that masks the issue rather than resolving it.

Any ideas what cold be causing this?

Comment: What file system are there in the source and target?

Comment: both use xfs on unraid

Comment: I have no experience of xfs. Let us hope that somebody who knows [better than I about your problem] will chip in and help you.

Comment: is it possible that your directories or folders get modified after rsync began ?

Comment: from unraid to unraid, I guess you don't need W switch. try use "a"  instead which preserve directory tree(s).